# Kotlin collections map causing a 'Type Checking Has Run Into A Recursive In Kotlin' error

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 classes lets call them A and B, I also have a function that converts an instance of A to an instance of B.

My code that is causing issues is basically:

```
fun fromAtoB(a: A) = B (fb1 = a.fa1, fb2 = a.fa2,  fb3 = a.fa3) 

val listOfA: List<A> = ...
val listOfB: listOfA.map { fromAtoB(it) }
```

This won't build due to the line:

```
fromAtoB(it)
```

With the error:

> Due to the error Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly

I Have no clue what I can do to fix this, Google had provided no results that seem to apply to my issue...

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**

Here are the actual source files:

- TenantEntity.kt - https://pastebin.com/mdSWiA1Y (Line 51 of this file
  is the issue)
- TenantDto.kt - https://pastebin.com/83UP9Cwe
- ReceiptEntity.kt - https://pastebin.com/BjP2ikg9
- ReceiptDto.kt - https://pastebin.com/Kpt9dSAp

Comment: Which version of kotlin do you use? I use 1.1.60 and it compiled that example.

Comment: Sergey Morozov I am also using 1.1.60

I am going to paste the full code in a second as it seems I have simplified away the issue :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of problem means that the compiler can't infer what the type of `listOfB` should be, because you have a recursive call somewhere in its definition. That's curious as I can't see any in your example code, but maybe you left out the offending code inadvertently. Anyways, this problem is usually resolved by doing what the error message suggests, manually specifying the return type like so:

```
val listOfB: List<B> = listOfA.map { fromAtoB(it) }
```

**Edit**:
After trying the real code, I just went after a hunch and changed line 45 in TenantEntity.kt from this:

```
fun fromDto(dto: TenantDto) = TenantEntity (
```

to this:

```
fun fromDto(dto: TenantDto): TenantEntity = TenantEntity (
```

and the error was gone. I'm not really sure why, but it should compile now.

**Second edit**:
Upon further inspection, you're going to run into a StackOverflowException with this code, which is ultimately why the compiler couldn't resolve the type. When you call `TenantEntity.fromDto(...)`, that will call `ReceiptEntity.fromDto(...)`, which will in turn call `TenantEntity.fromDto(...)`, and back again, into eternity (or the stack limit). That's not going to work, you'll need to fix your logic there.

Comment: I must have simplified something away especially given I do specify the return type as its a constructor argument :/

Comment: Just added full source

Comment: @leumas95 See my updated answer, I don't know why the compiler has a problem with it, but I found a way to fix it.

Comment: thanks for that, no clue why there is an issue either, would love to know but regardless I can build now so thanks again :)

Comment: @leumas95 Check my answer again - unfortunately, I've found another issue. The code still will not work, as you still have a recursion problem you'll need to solve, the compiler just doesn't complain to you about it anymore

Comment: ahh yes, I see the issue now thanks :) 
I will have to rethink this a tad

Comment: @leumas95 I dont understand, now the code compiles but there is an StackOverflowException in runtime?

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException Yes. It's not apparent from just the question, you'll have to look into the pastebin links. There's an infinite recursion hiding there, which leads to a stack overflow.